# Extract data between two phrases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, substr

I am trying to extract data between two sets of characters in MySQL. To keep the example somewhat simple, I am looking for the text between  and  in a column called STAGE_DATA.

Here is the SQL I have now:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(STAGE_DATA, 
    LOCATE('<title>',STAGE_DATA)+1, 
      (CHAR_LENGTH(STAGE_DATA) - LOCATE('<title>',REVERSE(STAGE_DATA)) 
      - LOCATE('</title>,STAGE_DATA))) 
FROM Stage_Table
```

But it is giving an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''&lt;/title&gt;,STAGE_DATA))) FROM Stage_Table' at line 5
```

Why?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you executing this code? The error suggests the string literal `<title>` has been entity encoded.  But in the last `LOCATE()`, I see there's a missing closing single quote for `'</title>'`: `- LOCATE('</title>,STAGE_DATA)`

Comment: Thank you! This got me in the right direction. The main issue was that I completely missed the single quote you pointed out.